# Best approach for tracking stock levels for custom line type items using Drupal Commerce

Tags: commerce

Does anyone have a best practice approach for tracking stock levels for custom line items that are configured to use product reference fields?

The custom line items are created used the [customizable products modules](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_custom_product) and use product reference fields to reference other products in the inventory.  When a product that references the custom line items is purchased, stock levels for the referenced products are not decremented properly.

Comment: Not sure, but you may need to configure the existing commerce_stock Rules in admin, to ensure your custom line item type is checked. It may also be easier in the 2.x branch.

Comment: Thanks for the response, David! The only line item that appears in the order is the parent product.  Customizable products adds additional fields that must be selected prior to adding the parent item to the cart.  The custom line item type includes three fields that use product reference fields that use the default product class, which has been configured to track stock levels.